# Installing SableCC in Eclipse Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, sablecc

I am trying to install SableCC in Eclipse in Linux machine. I have followed the instruction given on this http://web.archive.org/web/20090318023544/http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~sethhetu/rooms/Tutorials/EclipseAndSableCC.html, which is for Windows, but at step 9 I can not find the matching files for Linux machine.

The path I have tried given below:

Location: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/javaws

Working Directory: I chose "Browse Workspace..."

Arguments: -classpath /home/[user_name]/Downloads/sablecc-3.7/lib/sablecc.jar org.sablecc.sablecc.SableCC [Project_Name]

But still I get error message:

"netx: Invalid argument: net.sourceforge.jnlp.util.optionparser.InvalidArgumentException: [-classpath, /home/[user_name]/Downloads/sablecc-3.7/lib/sablecc.jar, org.sablecc.sablecc.SableCC, Project_Name]"

Ι also tried out changing the arguments from [Project_Name] to ${resource_name} given from "Variables...", but I get this error:

Variable references empty selection: ${resource_name}

Any idea?? Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Please put back the reference for the instructions

Comment: I put the link above, but it's http://web.archive.org/web/20090318023544/http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~sethhetu/rooms/Tutorials/EclipseAndSableCC.html

Answer (score 0):

A ready to use version http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sablecc/sablecc-3.7.zip , providing

```
sablecc-3.7/lib/sablecc.jar
           /bin/sablecc
```

bin/sablecc is a script, runs `java -jar sablecc.jar`

---

Building sablecc.jar : See `sablecc-3.7/doc/description.html